# change angular-nvd3 chart's key shape

Tags: nvd3.js, angular-nvd3

I want to change the "Events" key shape from circle to square but rather do so via angular-nvd3 or nvd3 api instead of selecting using d3 and changing it after the chart renders..
so far couldn't find how to do it

[image]

Comment: I used d3 eventually....

Comment: have you got any solution for this. Need to do same thing. @lironn

Comment: @Dalvik, there's no way doing it using their API as far as I know.. I used d3, see following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24413536/unable-to-change-legend-symbol-nvd3-bubble-chart