# nvD3 - multiBarChart - How to start from 0 and how to change the shape of controls

Tags: angular, d3.js, nvd3.js, angular-nvd3

I have added a [multiBarChart](http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/multiBarChart) in my app using [nvD3](http://nvd3.org/).

I am stuck in doing two things:

> 1. How to start it from 0.
>      My first bar is starting after leaving some space. I played with group spacing but it didn't work.

[image]

> 2. How do I change these circles into squares.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1) NVD3 allows you to reduce the spacing between bars using the `groupSpacing` function. You can try the following :

```
var chart = nv.models.multiBarChart()
        .groupSpacing(0)
```

2) Changing the shapes of the legend is not very straight forward. However, you can alter it fairly easily using d3 selections to manipulate its various parts.

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24413536/unable-to-change-legend-symbol-nvd3-bubble-chart) will help you with changing the shapes of the legend.

**#UPDATE**

Regarding your specific requirement for your first question,

> I just want them to start from 0 without leaving space

You can try the following code to manually select the element and move its position.

```
// TODO : Find a dynamic way to find translate(X,Y)
d3.select(".nv-barsWrap").attr('transform', 'translate(-10,0)');
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/shabeer90/uuvy9mp7/) is a working version of the code.

Hope it helps

Comment: @shabber I don't want to reduce the space between bars. I just want them to start from 0 without leaving space.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
        chart: {
            lines: {
                forceY: ([0])
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please add some sort of explanation or description to your answer.